# CakePHP 3.x: Add BelongsTo entity by using text input

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This issue seems pretty basic to me, so I would like to know where it goes wrong.

I will show my problem through a simple example. I create two tables with a simple **belongsTo** relation.

```
create table philosophers (
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    full_name varchar(255) not null unique
);
create table books (
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    title varchar(255) unique not null,
    philosopher_id int unsigned not null,
    foreign key `philosopher_id` (philosopher_id) references philosophers(id)
)
```

And bake everything on a fresh cakePHP 3.4.8 installation.
So far so good. Here's the catch:

I would like to write the Philosopher's name in a text box, and have CakePHP associate it with an existing name, if it is existing, or add a new one, if it is not yet existing. So, according to the conventions, I replace

```
echo $this->Form->control('philosopher_id', ['options' => $philosophers]);
```

in file **src/Template/Books/add.ctp**, with:

```
echo $this->Form->control('philosopher.full_name');
```

In the second case (adding a new entry), it works brilliantly, adding the foreign keys and all.

In order to achieve the first option, I have tried

- Implicitly setting `'checkExisting'` for the associated table in the `$entity->save()` phase.
- Making the `id` accessible in the `Philosopher` entity.
- Creating a Behavior that adds the id in the `beforeMarshal` event.

This is the Behavior:

**SEE BELOW**

It just doesn't seem to want to create the existing entity.
I know that I can do what it says [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations), but this practically bypasses validation entirely.

I am almost certain that I am missing something... Wish I knew what it is.

**EDIT: I updated and corrected the Behavior, taking @ndm 's solution into account.**

```
namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\ORM\Behavior;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use ArrayObject;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;

/**
 * This class prevents the belongsTo relation from
 * always creating new entries, by modifying the data
 * before it is marshalled.
 *
 * The config should have an entry called 'fields':
 *
 *  - 'fields' An array of field names, formatted
 *             according to cakePHP conventions
 *             for BelongsTo associations.
 */
class MarshalAssocBehavior extends Behavior {

    protected $_defaultConfig = [
        'fields' => []
    ];

    public function beforeMarshal (Event $event,
                                   ArrayObject $data,
                                   ArrayObject $options) {
        $fields = $this->getConfig('fields');
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $temp = explode('.', $field);
            $fd_name = $temp[0];
            $column = $temp[1];
            unset($temp);
            /*
             * If @$data does not contain required keys,
             * skip and evaluate next config block.
             */
            if (   !array_key_exists($fd_name, $data)
                || !array_key_exists($column, $data[$fd_name])
            ) continue;

            $table_name = Inflector::pluralize(Inflector::camelize($fd_name));
            $table = TableRegistry::get($table_name);

            /**
             * @var Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $result
             */
            $result = $table->find()
                            // value (user-provided) is escaped by Cake
                            ->where([$column => $data[$fd_name][$column]])
                            ->first();
            if ($result) {
                unset($data[$fd_name]);
                $data[$fd_name.'_id'] = $result->id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To incorporate it in my `BooksController`:

```
public function add() {
    $this->Books
         ->addBehavior('MarshalAssoc', [
                 'fields' => ['philosopher.full_name']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `beforeMarshal` to modify the data accordingly is the way to go, however you'd need to populate the foreign key in the books data instead, ie set `philosopher_id`, and remove `philosopher`:

```
unset($data['philosopher']);
$data['philosopher_id'] = $result->id;
```

`philosopher.id` would only be used when updating an existing record.

Also `TableRegistry::exists()` might bail out even if you wouldn't expect it to, as there might have no instance been set *yet*!

And last but not least, `where($data[$field])` is dangerous, it's a possible [**SQL injection**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sql-injection-prevention) vulnerability, as the key hand side of the passed array will be inserted into the query as is (the whole value could also be a string, which would be inserted as is too), and can potentially be defined by the user. If you want to use such configurable/reusable/dynamic functionality, then you should implement a whitelist for the fieldnames, and build the conditions array yourself.

Comment: Well, I tried the method from the book (getting the entity and setting it manually), and it fails.
So, it seems your suggestion is the only way to go. You are also correct re: sql injection. I would like to think I'd have noticed this, but I'm quite frustrated from this problem. That's beyond the point, however.
Do you think the way cakePHP deals with it is practical? I find it rather confusing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, if `checkExisting` does not actually check if the entity corresponds to an existing entry, what does it do?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're referring to with "_being practical_"? `checkExisting` does check whether a record exists, but only for entities that are marked as new (`EntityInterface::isNew()`) and have a primary key set, also this happens after marshalling, and things would also generally only be saved if there's at least 1 dirty/modified property on the entity... not sure in which context you've relied on that option. @NobbyNobbs